# HashMap repeats last elements in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap

I'm using HashMap to fetch values for my listview adapter.
The problem is that the last two elements of my HashMap are repeated.
I have tried different solutions before posting this question.
Some help would be highly appreciated, Thank you.

**Here is the code for my HashMap**

```
final String[] bookTitles = new String[]{
            "android-iconify",
            "Calligraphy",
            "SmartTabLayout",
            "android-viewpager-transformers",
            "Android-Rate",
            "FloatingActionButton",
            "TapTargetView",
            "MaterialDrawer"

    };
    final String[] authors = new String[]{

            "Version 2.2.2",
            "Version 2.2.0",
            "Version 1.6.1",
            "Version 1.0.1",
            "Version 1.0.1",
            "Version 1.6.4",
            "Version 1.11.0",
            "Version 6.0.8"


    };
    final String[] bookPages = new String[]{
            "Copyright 2015 Joan Zapata",
            "Copyright 2013 Christopher Jenkins",
            "Copyright (C) 2015 ogaclejapan\nCopyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project",
            "Copyright 2015 Georgi Eftimov",
            "Maintained by hotchemi",
            "Copyright 2015 Dmytro Tarianyk",
            "Copyright 2016 Keepsafe Software Inc.",
            "Copyright 2018 Mike Penz"


    };
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("title", bookTitles[i]);
        data.put("pages", bookPages[i]);
        data.put("author", authors[i]);


        authorList.add(data);

    }


    //Setup adapter
    customListViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), authorList);
    listView.setAdapter(customListViewAdapter);
```

And here is the code of my CustomListView adapter.

**CustomListView Adapter**

```
    package com.novamlineam.meezan;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;


public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> books;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {

        mContext = context;
        books = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return books.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null){

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryName);
            TextView author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryVersion);
            TextView pages = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryCopyright);

            HashMap<String, String> mBook = new HashMap<>();

            mBook = books.get(position);



            title.setText(mBook.get("title"));
            author.setText(mBook.get("author"));
            pages.setText(mBook.get("pages"));




        }


        return view;
    }
}
```

And here is the output that I get

[output of CustomListView Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWZOP.png) 
[remaining output of CustomListView Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIxsO.png)

Kindly help me.

Comment: I don't see any repeated data that you show us on the screenshot. Can you explain it properly ??

Comment: Thank you, problem was related to convertView, now it has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if (convertView == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryName);
    TextView author = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryVersion);
    TextView pages = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.libraryCopyright);

    HashMap<String, String> mBook = new HashMap<>();
    mBook = books.get(position);

    title.setText(mBook.get("title"));
    author.setText(mBook.get("author"));
    pages.setText(mBook.get("pages"));

    return view;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks alot. Solved my problem. :)